# fill multi index groupby pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, spaces, multi-index

Ok so I have this massive data set millions of rows and I have had trouble filtering the data with loc == and isin I suspect due to its size, so I have an idea I thought I would just do a multi index pivot_table then filter the smaller pivot table.  But obviously when I do the pivot I get a result like this:

```
    foo 2011 354
        2013 659
        2014 655
    bar 2012 645
        2013 665
```

I could filter this except I have spaces under the foo and the bar?   if these were nans I could just fill nans, but these are spaces, I am sure I have seen this before but I cant remember how to do it, how to fill the spaces under the foo and the bar??  once I have made this into a full data frame I can filter on this?

edit I am not sure why my original code will not run, it seems pretty straight forward?

```
    df2 = df1.loc[Mort_Data['COD_type'].isin(['T','U','V','W','Y','X'])]
```

Comment: Did you try `df.loc['foo']` or `df.loc[('foo',2011)]
`

Comment: I think it is only no display, all is correctly.

Comment: Sorry do you mean before or after I pivot the data?  I tried df.loc[df['Year'].isin(['2014'])] before I pivoted the data but it just would not run I assume the data was just too  large

Answer (score 0):

All the spaces under the foo are actually foo and same for bar. It is just a feature for easy visualization when multi-indexing. If you use reset_index() you will see them if what I suspect is true.

As for your other issue. Millions of rows is not that big, but if you are really having issues because of the size of the data then You can do it in batches. There are many options for this.